# Dynamic namespace rakes and parser classes with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have a collection of parsers that differ significantly in logic, but have the exact same methods and outputs.

I have devised somewhat of a master `Rake` and I am curious if what I have come up with could lead to some unexpected or weird behavior.

Essentially my `parse.rake` looks something like:

```
require 'app/models/provider'
require 'config/environment.rb'

Provider.all.each do |provider|  

    require "lib/tasks/#{provider.name}.rb"
    Kernel.const_get(provider.name).provider = provider

    namespace provider.name do      
      task :provider_task do #Parse method
        Kernel.const_get(provider.name).provider_task()
      end  
    end

end
```

Since classes are constants in ruby, `Kernel.const_get` is what I used to access class methods from a varname. My classes look like (`ABC.rb`):

```
Class ABC
    cattr_accessor :provider

    def self.provider_task()
        #Parse and add stuff to environment
    end
end
```

With this setup, I can easily invoke `rake ABC:provider_task` to run a specific parser. Also the `cattr_accessor` allows me to easily refer to the actual provider model. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this with no issues for a few weeks. After reviewing with some colleagues, I found a few who previously used a similar approach with no issues. Only potential danger is naming conflicts with your ruby classes.