# Undefined capistrano's method through my module

Tags: ruby, rake, capistrano

I'm writing rake task in capistrano.

I thought that I'm able to use `info` method similarly from `method1` and `method2` in `run_locally`, but I got error in `method2`.

What's happend...

How do I resolve this?

Should I wrap `info` with `run_locally` once again in `Sample:method2`? ( but I refuse it...)

**environment**

- Capistrano Version: 3.4.0 (Rake Version: 10.4.2)

**code**

```
namespace :sample do
  task :task1 do
    run_locally do
      method1('task1')
      Sample::method2('task1')
    end
  end

  def method1(str)
    info "> called method1 str:#{str}"
  end
end

module Sample
  extend Rake::DSL
  extend self

  def method2(str)
    info "> called method2 str:#{str}"
  end

  public :method2
end
```

**output**

```
$ bundle exec cap beta sample:task1
INFO > called method1 str:task1
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `info' for Sample:Module
/capistrano/lib/capistrano/tasks/util.rake:22:in `method2'
/capistrano/lib/capistrano/tasks/util.rake:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/capistrano/lib/capistrano/tasks/util.rake:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => sample:task1
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Well yeah, when you call `method2`, control goes there. And there's no `info` method for `Sample` (it's no longer capistrano's context).

Comment: There a few ways to go around this, but they differ. And it's impossible to tell which one is appropriate for your case.

Comment: Thank you Sergio Tulentsev. I read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172292/scope-of-rakes-in-a-rails-project and I'm using module for set same name method in other namespaces. But capistrano context is lost with using module, I should relinquish...